# beautifulsoup: finding specific class name in nested div

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I try to get reviews in agoda site for analysis by using beautifulsoup

i have inspected and see that the reviews is in :

```
<div class="container-agoda">
    <div class="a">
        <div class="b">
            <div class="c">
                <div class="d">
                    <div class="col-xs-9 review-comment" data-selenium="comments-detail">>
                        <div name="review-title" class="title" data-selenium="comments-title">
                            HAD 1 HOUR SLEEP
                        </div>
                        <div class="review-comment-section">
                            <div class="comment-detail" data-selenium="reviews-comments">
                                <span>Great location</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but this class in nested in 10+ classes

I have tried by

```
for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={"class":"comment-detail"}):
    print(div)
```

but it get nothing.

Is it have a method for get an exactly as find ''' class="comment-detail" data-selenium="reviews-comments" ''' or any suggestion.

Thank you.

Comment: Your code is working well (tested with python3 and bs4): http://pastebin.com/BLcNjnNL

Comment: Are you sure you have these reviews in the HTML source that you are parsing?